# Strategies to free up space in /

Tags: disk-usage, cuda

In my effort to install CUDA 10 am getting a lot of 'unmet dependency' errors.

So am running

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

And the result of this command is

> You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/

What are some strategies to help free up space? I assume this means anything in my root/ directory.

Comment: You can remove all of the ~/.cache files. And you can run the command " sudo apt auto-remove" to remove the apt caches.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: Please [edit your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1243935/edit) to show us the complete output of `df -h`

Answer (score 1):

personally, I use Stacer to clean up space. it's very friendly

sudo apt install stacer

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the contents of `~/.cache` directory and try removing the apt cache via :

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

But some programs might use different directory for their caches ( e.g Telegram-desktop portable application writes its cache into the `~/.local/share/TelegramDesktop/tdata` in my system) .

And an important one :
Try deleting the systemd journals in the `/var/log/journal` if you don't want to debug your systemd. You can limit the amount of logs that journal can have at a time by running :

```
 journalctl --vacuum-size=some_size
```

Please read the [Journalctl manpage](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/journalctl/).
You can see the space currently occupied by journals :

```
journalctl --disk-usage
```

And you can use some [nice programs](https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-disk-analyzer-tools-for-linux-system/) to see what are eating your freespace.

If anybody has a more complete solution , I'm glad to hear.